What the best practice to render a list in React.js without unique IDs?
I used to use the index as the key when rendering a list for a long time. However, I encountered a bug when attempting to reorder the list.
After conducting research and reading the official documentation, I realized that using the index as the key is not a good choice. Other methods, such as using UUIDs, may introduce additional problems, such as triggering unnecessary re-renders or losing component state.
Any good thoughts?
const toBeRendered = ['a','b','c','c'];
// array with no id and duplicated elements
// add/delete/reorder


If you don't have unique identifiers then create artificial ones. It's not clear what "additional problems" you foresee with that method

uuid can sure fix the problem.But the key varys every single time.

So create the keys only once

If your data is static you can take data out of the component like this:
const dataWithKeys = data.map((el, i) => ({ ...el, uniqKey: i }));

In this case, keys will be truly unique.
With server data you can use this approach:
const dataWithKeys = useMemo(
   () => data.map((el, i) => ({ ...el, uniqKey: `${i} ${el}` })),
   [data]
)

When you need to change the element, new render will occur in any case.
If your data is a list of strings, renders will be very cheap anyway. Otherwise, you should try to 'compose' a unique key from several values of object:
{data.map(el => (
    <div key={`${el?.name} ${el.lastName} ${el.registrationDate}`}>
       {el.name}
    </div>
))}

